# SQL Query on table with 30mill records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have been having problems building a table in my local SQL Server. Orginally it was causing the tempdb table to become full and throw an exception. This has a lot of joins and outer applies, and so to find specifically where the problem lay I did a select on the first table in the sql query to determine how long it took, that was fast so I then added the next table that was the first join in the query and reran, I continued to do this until I found the table that stalled.

I found the problem (or at least the first problem) was with the shipper_container table. This table is huge and pulling it alone gets a System.OutOfMemoryException just showing a select on the results of that table alone (it has only 5 columns). It cuts out at 16 million records but has 30 million rows.  It is 1.2GB in size. This doesn't seem so big for me that SQL Management studio couldn't handle it.

Using a WHERE statement to collect values between 1 January - 10 January 2015 still resulted in a search that took over 5  minutes and was still executing when I cancelled.  I have also added indexes on each of the select parameters and this did not increase performance either.

Here is the SQL Query. You can see I have commented out the other parameters that have yet to be added in other joins and outer applies.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME
DECLARE @Shipper_Key INT = NULL
DECLARE @Part_Key INT = NULL

SET @startDate = '2015-01-01'
SET @endDate = '2015-01-10'

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

INSERT Shipped_Container
(
    Ship_Date,  
    Invoice_Quantity,
    Shipper_No,
    Serial_No,
    Truck_Key,
    Shipper_Key
)
SELECT
    S.Ship_Date,
    SC.Quantity,
    S.Shipper_No,
    SC.Serial_No, 
    S.Truck_Key,
    S.Shipper_Key
    FROM Shipper AS S
JOIN Shipper_Line AS SL
    --ON SL.PCN = S.PCN
    ON SL.Shipper_Key = S.Shipper_Key
JOIN Shipper_Container AS SC
    --ON SC.PCN = SL.PCN
    ON SC.Shipper_Line_Key = SL.Shipper_Line_Key
WHERE S.Ship_Date >= @startDate AND S.Ship_Date <= @endDate
    AND S.Shipper_Key = ISNULL(@Shipper_Key, S.Shipper_Key)
    AND SL.Part_Key = ISNULL(@Part_Key, SL.Part_Key)
```

The server instance is run on the local network - could this be an issue? I really have minimal experience at this and would really appreciate help and as detailed and clear as possible. Often in SQL forums people jump right into technical details I don't follow so well.

Comment: A good thing would be to post the execution plan. You can export that from SQL Server Management Studio in XML format, which would be easiest to use for most, rather than posting a picture with the plan. Also, letting us know what indexes (and their type) are on the table could help.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't do** a `Select ... From yourtable` in SS Management Studio when it return 
hundrend  of thousand or millions of row. 1GB of data gets a lot bigger when the system has to draw and show it on screen in the Management Studio data sheet

> The server instance is run on the local network

When you do a `Select ... From yourtable` in SSMS, the server must send all the data to your laptop/desktop. This is quite a lot of uneeded presure on the network.
It should not be an issue when you insert because everything stays on the server. However, staying on the server does not mean it will be fast if your data model is not good enough.

> SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

You may get dirty data is you use that... It may be better to remove it unless you know why it is there and why you need it.

> I have also added indexes on each of the select parameters and this did not increase performance either

If you mean indexes on :

- S.Ship_Date,
- SC.Quantity,
- S.Shipper_No,
- SC.Serial_No,
- S.Truck_Key,
- S.Shipper_Key

What are their definitions ? 
If they are individual indexes on 1 column, you can drop indexes on SC.Quantity, S.Shipper_No, SC.Serial_No and S.Truck_Key. They are not used.
Ship_Date and Shipper_key may be usefull. It all depends on your model and existing primary keys. (which you need to describe, see below)

> It will help to give a more accurate answer if you could tell us:

- the relation between your 3 tables (which field link A to B and in which direction)
- the primary key on your 3 tables
- a complete list of all your indexes(and columns) on your 3 tables

If none of your indexes are usefull or if they are missing, it will most likely read the whole 3 tables and try to match them. Because it is pretty big, it does not have enough memory to process it and it uses tempdb to store intermediary data.

> For now I will suppose that shipper_key + PCN is the primary key on each tables. 
>   I think you can try that:

- You can create an index on S.Ship_Date

  ```
  Create Index Shipper_Line_Ship_Date(Ship_Date) -- subject to updates according to your Primary Key
  ```
- The query optimizer may not use the indexes (if they exists) with such a where clause:

  ```
  AND S.Shipper_Key = ISNULL(@Shipper_Key, S.Shipper_Key)
  AND SL.Part_Key = ISNULL(@Part_Key, SL.Part_Key)
  ```

  you can use:

  ```
  AND (S.Shipper_Key = @Shipper_Key or @Shipper_Key is null)
  AND (SL.Part_Key = @Part_Key or @Part_Keyis null)
  ```
- It would help to have indexes on Shipper_Key and PCN

> Finally

As I already said above, we need to know more about your data model (create table...), primary keys and indexes (create indexes). You can create a modele here http://sqlfiddle.com/ with all 3 create tables and their indexes. Then go to link and add the link here.

In SSMS, you can right click on a table and go to `Script Table as / Create To / New Query Window` and add it here or in http://sqlfiddle.com/. Only keep the `CREATE TABLE ...` part down to the first `GO`.
You can then do the same thing on all you indexes.

You should also add a copy of you query plan. 
In SSMS, go to `Query menu / Display Estimated Execution Plan` and right click to save it as xml (xml is better). It is only an estimation and it won't execute the whole query. It should be pretty fast.